# Output of bash script in perl script

Tags: perl, bash

I want to embed a bash script inside  a perl script. I want to run my bash script by taking some variables from the perl script. Once it gets the variable the bash script takes over and tries to output the files that is created within.

How can I pass the perl script variable to my bash script ?

I do not know perl  but from what I read in Google, I can embed my bash script as

```
system("get_files.cmd -yr ${year}");
```

where my bash script is `get_files.cmd`.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Just try it with `perl -e 'my $year = 5; system("get_files.cmd -yr ${year}");'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be better if you passed them as arguments to your bash script.

The perl call:

```
system("get_files.cmd ${var1} ${var2}");
```

The bash script

```
var1="$1"
var2="$2"
...
```

Where `$1`, `$2` are the arguments passed in the command line (in order). Note that you can use the `$#` bash variable to get the number of arguments passed.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

The Expect module can essentially automate shell tasks such as running scripts and passing perl variables. Such that:

```
Use Expect;

  # create an Expect object by spawning another process
  my $exp = Expect->spawn($command, @params)
    or die "Cannot spawn $command: $!\n";
```

http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod